# Cant run JavaScript tagged template from within imported object

Tags: javascript, class, oop, webpack, string-literals

I am trying to convert a websites JavaScript into chucks compatible with webpack bundling, basically i need to export/import the needed scripts for a multi page website and then pack them into 1 file per page, it do however cause me some troubles

The script worked perfectly fine before but now it do not work as previously

I have a templater function that use string listerals and string manipulation the templater function is originally inspired by [this](https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/) post, it is however modified a bit

```
   export const templater = (parts) => {
        return (data) => {
            let res = parts[0];
    
            for (let i=1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                const val = arguments[i];
                if (typeof val == "function") {
                    res += val(data);
                } else {
                    if (data) {
                        if(data.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
                            res += data[val];
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                res += parts[i];
            }
            return res;
        }
    };
```

I have a script that handles the string literal its an object with the key 'template' which calls the imported templater function

```
import {templater} from '../functions/cc-templater-function.js';

export let complianceHandler = {
    template: templater`
        <div class="compliance-overlay">
            <div id="compliance-wrapper" class="compliance-wrapper ${'type'}">
                <p class="compliance-message">${'message'}</p>
                <button id="compliance-yes" data-answer="yes">Yes</button><button id="compliance-no" data-answer="no">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
}
```

I have this script which passes the JavaScript object to the handler which uses it in the templater function

```
import {complianceHandler } from './objects/cc-compliance-handler-object.js';
        
export let testObject = {
   remove: () => {
      document.querySelector('#myelem').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", complianceHandler.template({
                        message: 'Are you sure you want to do this?'
      }));
   }
}
```

The above is a simplified/stripped version of the real code

When the `testObject.remove()` is called i get this error: `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`
I cant see the method/function named `call` anywhere, i'm kinda lost at this point on how to debug and fix this

1. Everything bundles fine when bundling with webpack
2. Everything works this way in the normal code that are not bundled with webpack and exported/imported (the old code)

Does anybody know how to solve this? i have tried to modify the code in various ways, but i continue to get the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
export let complianceHandler = {
    template: templater`
        <div class="compliance-overlay">
            <div id="compliance-wrapper" class="compliance-wrapper ${'type'}">
                <p class="compliance-message">${'message'}</p>
                <button id="compliance-yes" data-answer="yes">Yes</button><button id="compliance-no" data-answer="no">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
}
```

This is exporting an object with a `template` *string* property generated from calling the `templater` function.

Later on, you're importing this and trying to *call* the `template` property. Since it's a string, *calling* it doesn't make sense:

```
complianceHandler.template({
  message: 'Are you sure you want to do this?'
})
```

It sounds like what you're wanting to do is to make `template` a *function* instead:

```
export let complianceHandler = {
    template: ({ type, message }) => templater`
        <div class="compliance-overlay">
            <div id="compliance-wrapper" class="compliance-wrapper ${type}">
                <p class="compliance-message">${message}</p>
                <button id="compliance-yes" data-answer="yes">Yes</button><button id="compliance-no" data-answer="no">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
}
```

Notice I also fixed the template placeholders (`${type}`, not `${'type'}` so the variable is used, not the literal string `'type'`). It should also be noted that if you want to generate *valid HTML*, you should be HTML-encoding your variables before inserting into the HTML unless you want the variables to be HTML instead of text.

Comment: Nope dosent work.. its also supposed to be 'type' etc cause its string manipulation, it is just returning the function now... i start to believe its a problem with how webpack packs it..

Comment: The problem was with how webpack packed the javascript.. i had to do this part ({ type, message }) => but i also had to make the function inside templater a self invoking function before it would run as it previously did without webpack packing it

Comment: No now it does not take in the variables... i give up, its broken when i run it through webpack bundling...

Comment: For some reason webpack wount bundle the script so that a tagged template runs as a function as it normally do by etc mykey: templater``... it wount recognize it as a function after being bundled